# how to cross check all the tables in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application, where the backend is using MySQL DB. And in this database, there are two standard columns "time_created" and "time_updated" in each table.  As the name suggested, the first column records the current timestamp when the row is being inserted, while the 2nd one is for either inserted or updated action.

My Question is, is it possible to have a way to find out any rows in any table that are being "touched", when I click the "save" button in the frontend ?  Is there a SQL way to do that ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: What do you mean by "touched"? And what does the save button in the application do?

Comment: I want to find out what rows in which tables are being either insert or update when I click this "save" button from frontend.

Comment: Do you want the rows to be returned or just updated in the table someway with an transaction identifier which you can use to look up the rows?

Comment: My mysql is built on K8S.  I am not sure if there is UI way to locate such rows. Is there an SQL  way to do that ?

Comment: Let's say I just want the table name list, where the rows being changed for the last minute. Is that possible ?